# Impala raise " AnalysisException: Syntax error" when using ROW_NUMBER() OVER

Tags: sql, hive, subquery, impala

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT MONTH_ID, 'Total' AS cola, colb
FROM
(
    SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH_ID,col3 ORDER BY col4 DESC) AS ROWN
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT A.*, B.col3
            FROM table1 A
            LEFT JOIN table2 B
            ON A.col1 = B.col1
        ) A
)
WHERE ROWN=1
GROUP BY MONTH_ID
```

If I create a intermediate table with the subqueries this query can work. But when I run entire thing Impala will raise: "AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 12:undefined: WHERE ROWN = 1 ^ Encountered: WHERE Expected: AS, DEFAULT, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error"

I tried run this in Hive, different error shows: "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 20:4 cannot recognize input near 'WHERE' 'ROWN' '=' in subquery source"

Then I tried same query in oracle, it works...

Could anyone explain why this is happening and how to solve this?
Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Subquery should have some alias like this (see comment in the code):

```
SELECT MONTH_ID, 'Total' AS cola, colb
FROM
(
    SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH_ID,col3 ORDER BY col4 DESC) AS ROWN
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT A.*, B.col3
            FROM table1 A
            LEFT JOIN table2 B
            ON A.col1 = B.col1
        ) A
) B ----------------------------Alias is a must --------------
WHERE ROWN=1
GROUP BY MONTH_ID, colb -----All columns which are not aggregated and not constants should be in GROUP BY
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!! The group by statement is right in my original query I just got lazy when I type the question xd, but thank you for point out.